# How to use MAX ( COUNT (*)) in my SQL function?

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

```
SELECT F.origin, F.destination, COUNT(DISTINCT E.ename), COUNT(F.flno)
FROM Flights F, Employees E, Certified C, Aircraft A
WHERE E.eid = C.eid AND E.salary > 100000 AND A.aid = C.aid AND F.distance >= A.cruisingrange
GROUP BY E.ename, F.origin, F.destination
HAVING (COUNT(F.flno)) = 14
```

The thing is that `14` is the `max(count(F.flno))` of the table but I don't know how to transform all of this to replace that `14` for the maximum number of a column based on `COUNT(F.flno)`

Comment: Besides what @GordonLinoff said; any field in your select NOT in an aggregate function should be in your GROUP BY. If your DB doesn't complain about that then you must be using MySQL. Set ```ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY``` and it should complain.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do this, in sql server, in other databases there would be the top equivalent which you can check.

```
 with source_qry
   as(
    SELECT F.origin, F.destination, COUNT(DISTINCT E.ename), COUNT(F.flno) as cnt_flno
      FROM Flights F, 
           Employees E, 
           Certified C, 
           Aircraft A
     WHERE E.eid = C.eid 
       AND E.salary > 100000 
       AND A.aid = C.aid 
       AND F.distance >= A.cruisingrange
    GROUP BY E.ename, F.origin, F.destination
         )
select top 1* 
  from source_qry
order by cnt_flno desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT F.origin, F.destination, COUNT(DISTINCT E.ename), COUNT(F.flno)
FROM Flights F, Employees E, Certified C, Aircraft A
WHERE E.eid = C.eid AND E.salary > 100000 AND A.aid = C.aid AND F.distance >= A.cruisingrange
GROUP BY E.ename, F.origin, F.destination
ORDER BY 4 DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH data AS (
    SELECT F.origin, F.destination, COUNT(DISTINCT E.ename) AS cnt_ename, COUNT(F.flno) AS cnt,
        MAX(COUNT(F. flno)) OVER () AS maxcnt
    FROM Flights F, Employees E, Certified C, Aircraft A
    WHERE E.eid = C.eid AND E.salary > 100000 AND A.aid = C.aid AND F.distance >= A.cruisingrange
    GROUP BY E.ename, F.origin, F.destination
)
SELECT * FROM data WHERE cnt = maxcnt;
```

This will handle ties in the maximum count. Get away from the habit of using `top` and `limit` indiscriminately.